# Difference Equation with exponential function

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponential-function

How do I express this recursive function in implicit form? (Please show working out)

$$K_{(n)}=2K_{(n-1)}+\frac{4^{n-1}-1}3$$

$$K_{(0)}=1$$

This is my proposed upper bound for the Koch Art Gallery Problem (https://file.scirp.org/pdf/OJDM20120400004_11740065.pdf), where 'n' is equal to the iteration of the Koch curve and the value returned is the maximum number of guards required for full vision inside the koch curve polygon. I can find the recursive function, however as I was never formally taught how to solve first order difference equations with exponentional functions, I am unaware how to progress.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. We came here to learn and help each other, not producing answer keys. Please take a few minutes to read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS THE SOLUTION BEFORE OP EDITED THE QUESTION ON SEPT 15.

Let $K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^n +  R_{(n)}$, then we have 
$$
K_{(n)}=2K_{(n-1)}+\frac{4^n-1}3 \quad \rightarrow \quad R_{(n)}=2R_{(n-1)}-\frac{1}3
$$

*Note that in here, the original condition as posted by the OP was $\frac{4^{\color{Red}{ n}}-1}3$ instead of the new edit $\frac{4^{\color{Red}{ n-1}}-1}3$*

The recursive equation for the remainder $R_{(n)}$ can be solved by setting $R_{(n)} = c \cdot a^n + b$ which gives
$$
c \;  a \; a^{n-1} + b=2 \; c \; a^{n-1} + 2 b -\frac{1}3
$$
i.e. $a=2$ and $b = \frac{1}3$, with arbitrary $c$.
In total, we obtain a general solution

$K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^n +  c\; 2^n + \frac{1}3$

Satisfying  $K_{(0)} =1$ demands $ \frac23 +  c + \frac{1}3= 1$, i.e. $c=0$, hence

$K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^n +  \frac{1}3$

For other initial conditions, we obtain different $c$. If $K_{(-1)} =1$ (see the OPs comment), we have  $1 = \frac23 4^{-1} +  c\; 2^{-1} + \frac{1}3$, i.e. $c=1$, hence in this case

$K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^n +   2^n + \frac{1}3$

Comment: You are a wonderful human being

Comment: The solution you gave prior was correct as the sequence is 1,2,5,15,51...I have ascertained this empirically. All I had to do was input (n-1) for the correct values in your previously proposed formula. For example: K(0)=(2/3)*4^(-1)+2^(-1)+(1/3)=1.

Comment: Ok but this is another intial condition, different from $K_{(0)}=1$ which you gave in the original task description. Indeed, what you describe now is   $K_{(-1)}=1$ and I put the solution in the main text.

Comment: My initial condition is K(0)=1, which is achieved with this formula: $$K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^{(n-1)} +   2^{(n-1)} + \frac{1}3$$, If this is the correct formula, then how is the recurisve relation which I have written wrong?

Comment: If you put your proposed solution $K_{(n)} = \frac23 4^{(n-1)} +   2^{(n-1)} + \frac{1}3$ into the required recursive relation $K_{(n)}=2K_{(n-1)}+\frac{4^n-1}3 $, then what you get is 
$$
\frac23 4^{(n-1)} +   2^{(n-1)} + \frac{1}3 {{?\atop = }\atop {\;}} 2 \left(\frac23 4^{(n-2)} +   2^{(n-2)} + \frac{1}3\right) + \frac{4^n-1}3 
$$
After cancelling equal terms, this gives 
$
\frac1{6} 4^{n}  {{?\atop = }\atop {\;}} \frac1{12} 4^{n} + \frac{4^n}3 
$ which is wrong. So this is not a solution.

Comment: After further evaluation I realise that the recursive relation I gave you was faulty, I have edited it. Does the formula I propose fit now?

Comment: With the edit the terms cancel out.

Comment: Uhhh, a bit stressful, editing the original question. Although the approach remains the same, it takes going through the details again.....

Comment: OK I leave it to you to change the solution as you have re-edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION INSPIRED BY ANDREAS

Let $K_{(n)} = \frac16 4^n +  R_{(n)}$, as $2\frac{4^{n-1}}3 =\frac16 4^n$

$$K_{(n)}=2K_{(n-1)}+\frac{4^{n-1}-1}3 \quad \rightarrow \quad R_{(n)}=2R_{(n-1)}-\frac13$$

and the recursive equation for the remainder $R(n)$ can be solved by setting $R(n)=c⋅a^n+b$ which gives

$$c \;  a \; a^{n-1} + b=2 \; c \; a^{n-1} + 2 b -\frac{1}3$$

i.e. $a=2$ and $b=\frac13$, with arbitrary c. In total, we obtain a general solution

$K(n)=\frac16 4^n+c2^n+\frac13$

Satisfying $K(0)=1$ demands $\frac16+c+\frac13=1$, i.e. $c=\frac12$, hence

$K(n)=\frac16 4^n+2^{n-1}+\frac13$

Comment: That should resolve the previous inconsistencies.